# android studio - how to force AVD to use square app icon stead of circle

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am using Pixel in emulator, which shows circle icon for the app.

But for my real device, the icon is square which makes becoming too small with a white background.(I am using Honeywell).

I tried to go to [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher) to make some good icon, but turns out the icon still too small.

Any ways I can fix it/Can I try on AWD for testing?